# How to move forward and possibly backward a specified number of steps in a python list?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to make a board game in Python. However, I'm stuck with a portion of it.

For example:

If you have a list:

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'E']

A player can roll 1-6 and can start at any position other than 'E' as that's the winning space. If the player is at index 3, or value 4, and rolls a 3 they land on the 'E' space and everything is fine. However, if they roll a 6 for instance, they would move 3 steps forward to the 'E' value and then 'bounce back' 3 spaces back to index 3 or value 4 for a total of 6 moves. If they start at index 5, and roll a 5 they would go back to index 2 for a total of 5 moves etc. I'm not sure how to implement something like this or if there would be a better way to structure this instead? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe they want the player to start from the beginning, rather they want the player to hit the end of the list and then move backward for the rest of the steps they have left.

Comment: That is correct @DominicBeyer and your answer worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this; I have start assigned as index 3, aka '4' in the list.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'E']

start = 3
roll = 6

if start + roll >= len(lst):
    finish = 2 * len(lst) - 2 - (start + roll)
else:
    finish = start + roll
print(lst[finish])
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: It's on index three, but my code prints out `lst[finish]`, so the fourth item, aka 4.
The list starting at 1 gets confusing with indexing, I had to triple check this because I kept doubting myself.

Comment: Well, if you're starting at index 6, you're at the finish, and shouldn't move at all.
Starting at number 6, aka index 5, my code ends at number 2, which is index 1. Makes sense, you move forward 1 to get to 'E', and move back 5 to land on 2.

Comment: Please see my comment on the post itself, I don't believe that you are thinking about the question correctly, they want to move backward not restart.

Comment: @DominicBeyer, you are correct. The point of the question was to "go backwards" once you hit the end of the list, not "start over". Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small logic which might help. I am not sure how are you inputting your first value (randomizing it or inputting) but you can change this up a little to fix what you need.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'E']


lost = 1 #to loop
count = 0 #to remember the carry
while(lost):
    number = int(input("What do you wanna role? "))
    if number > 0 and number < 7: 
        newVal = number+count
        if newVal > 6:
            subtract = 6 - newVal
            newVal = 6+subtract
        elif lst[newVal] == "E":
            print("WIN")
            lost = 0;
        count = newVal;
        print(newVal)
    else:
        print("Number should be in 1-6")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace all print(current_position) variables in while loop with your list: print(list1[current_position-1]), which would basically be the same. You can also change everything with your list, I just don't see any point in doing that unless you really really really need to iter like that through your list.

```
    import random
    
    Running = True
    current_position = int(input('select a number 1-6: '))
    
    while Running == True:
        option = str(input('type Y to roll, type Q to quit: '))
        if option == 'Y':
            roll = random.randint(1,6)
            print('current position: ',current_position)
            print('rolled number: ',roll)
            if (current_position + roll) == 7:
                print(f'!!!!!!!!Congatulations !!!!!!!!, You have scored {current_position + roll}')
                Running = False
            if (current_position + roll)>7:
                current_position = (current_position-(6-roll))
                print('current_position: ',current_position)
            elif  (current_position + roll) <= 6:
                current_position = current_position + roll
                print('current position: ',current_position)
        else: Running = False
```

outputs:

```
    select a number 1-6: 3
    type Y to roll, type Q to quit: Y
    current position:  3
    rolled number:  2
    current position:  5
    type Y to roll, type Q to quit: Y
    current position:  5
    rolled number:  1
    current position:  6
    type Y to roll, type Q to quit: Y
    current position:  6
    rolled number:  4
    current_position:  4
    type Y to roll, type Q to quit: Y
    current position:  4
    rolled number:  3
    !!!!!!!!Congatulations !!!!!!!!, You have scored 7
```